# Grails - hibernate upgrade from 3 to 4

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am getting following error during compilation.

```
/home/******/Desktop/******/******/src/groovy/org/grails/list/ListDistinct.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl
   ^

/home/*****/Desktop/******/******/src/groovy/org/grails/list/ListDistinct.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria
```

I made an upgrade of hibernate from version 3 to version 4. Does anyone know where are this classes in hibernate 4 or were they replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.Alpha2/org/hibernate/impl/CriteriaImpl.java

You should probably change `org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl` to `org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl`

The same for the second class: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.0.0.Alpha2/org/hibernate/impl/CriteriaImpl.java